# CSS package as a node module

Tags: css, node.js, npm

Is it possible to create a node module that contains only CSS files served in git that I could call through dependencies in package.json

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "isLocal": "true",
  "devDependencies": {
    "core-css": "git+ssh://git@git.myproject:porject/core-css.git",
    "node-sass": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0"
  }
```